# MSTest : Writing Unit Tests with TestContext

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, mstest

I am in the process of writing some unit tests which creates files.

At the moment I am using `TestContext` **TestResultsDirectory** to store created file (results to assert).  The syntax looks like:

```
        //Create directory
        Directory.CreateDirectory(TestContext.TestResultsDirectory);

        //Create file.
        File.Create(TestContext.TestResultsDirectory + @"\Test.txt");
```

My question basically is why `TestResultsDirectory` is not created?

When I just call `File.Create`, test fails with `DirectoryNotFoundException`.

Is this the correct way of using `TestContext` or are there any attribute such as `[SetPath]` which we can set at method level so that the runtime will create the "test related" paths?

Comment: Technically you are not creating a 'unit test', because unit tests run in isolation and don't communicate with external resources such as database, system clock and file system.

Comment: Conceptually yes, you are correct. The test is to update a text file and make sure it contains the correct text. For auditing purposes we must make sure the "change" is stored in the file. Since test-context is generated by the run-time, the tests can run by any developer (thats the key for choosing test-context). Little bit confused why test-context just have pointers to directories that does not exists.

Comment: Where did you search for the created directory? Did you try System.Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(TestContext.TestResultsDirectory, "Test.txt"))) ?

Comment: I copied the TestContext.TestResultsDirectory property content and checked using file explorer. There is a "Guid" directory name in this path.

Comment: When I create files in my tests, I always use a hardcoded path in `File.Create()`. I never like having dynamic code in tests since I want to make sure each time that test is run, I always use static, expected, values. I'd highly recommend creating a temp folder that you can dump your txt files into, rather then using dynamic runtime properties like TestContext.TestResultsDirectory`. It's just my preference though, not a rule.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but I'm just now learning about this stuff myself, and I just stumbled on the answer to your question about the `TestResultsDirectory` folder while playing with Visual Studio automated testing. Mayhaps it'll help someone else.

`TestResultsDirectory` *is* created, just not *during* the test. (@Kevin, having a GUID for a name has nothing to do with whether a folder can be created, if that's what you were implying.) I've followed the creation of files and folders while the test is running, and the folder is not created until *after the user code has exited*.

When running a test where screen video is captured (`ScreenCapture.wmv`) or an action log is created (`UITestActionLog.html`), results files are placed in `TestResultsDirectory` *after it has been created*, which is not until after your code is finished. If your test doesn't create these or similar results files, this folder will most likely not be created.

As I said, I'm still learning about Visual Studio testing.

UPDATE: I've found that when recording video or an action log, they seem to be stored *in memory* until the test finishes. That seems to be the reason the output folder is created after the user code exits.

If I find out more on this topic (and if the site lets me - can you edit an answer more than once?), I'll update this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I never use the TestContext. In this case I would use Environment.CurrentDirectory instead:

```
    //Create directory
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "SubDirectory"));

    //Create file.
    File.Create(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Test.txt"));
```

Comment: I was just cleaning some test cases today that used the same pattern (current directory) and ended up creating folders in the root folder.  I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [`TestContext.ResultsDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.resultsdirectory.aspx) instead.  This seems to point to a directory that actually gets created.

[`TestContext.TestResultsDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.testresultsdirectory.aspx) does not get created (it has the GUID folder in the path) and that is why you get the `DirectoryNotFoundException`.